# undefined method 'title'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting an error on the show action when new guidelines are being added to my app.  This is since I changed the show action to allow for custom routes...The new guideline is added to the database correctly...

My show action in guidelines_controller.rb is

```
def show
    @guideline = Guideline.where(title: params[:title]).first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @guideline }

    end
  end
```

model guidelines.rb is

```
attr_accessible :content, :hospital, :title, :user_id, :guideline_id, :specialty
```

show view is

```
<p>Title: <%= link_to @guideline.title, seeguideline_path(@guideline.title) %> </p
```

Error message is

console says...

```
Started POST "/guidelines" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-22 17:07:29 +1100
Processing by GuidelinesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bQKIkSb4Wzr46FERMbU82Q1qMzd3GrGNq6Nqmr0KNhY=", "guideline"=>{"title"=>"Stackoverflo", "specialty"=>"Dermatology", "hospital"=>"Stack Hospital", "content"=>"www.stackoverflow.com"}, "commit"=>"Create Guideline"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 11 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Guideline Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "guidelines" WHERE (LOWER("guidelines"."hospital") = LOWER('Stack Hospital') AND "guidelines"."title" = 'Stackoverflo') LIMIT 1
  SQL (65.0ms)  INSERT INTO "guidelines" ("content", "created_at", "hospital", "specialty", "subtitle", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "www.stackoverflow.com"], ["created_at", Fri, 22 Feb 2013 06:07:29 UTC +00:00], ["hospital", "Stack Hospital"], ["specialty", "Dermatology"], ["subtitle", nil], ["title", "Stackoverflo"], ["updated_at", Fri, 22 Feb 2013 06:07:29 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 11]]
  SOLR Request (152.5ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007f9c79f2fc48> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><add><doc><field name="id">Guideline 35</field><field name="type">Guideline</field><field name="type">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name="class_name">Guideline</field><field name="title_text">Stackoverflo</field></doc></add>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]
   (3.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/guidelines/35
  SOLR Request (100.3ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007f9c79f2fc48> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><commit/>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]
Completed 302 Found in 485ms (ActiveRecord: 69.8ms)


Started GET "/guidelines/35" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-22 17:07:30 +1100
Processing by GuidelinesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"35"}
  Guideline Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "guidelines".* FROM "guidelines" WHERE "guidelines"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "35"]]
  Guideline Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "guidelines".* FROM "guidelines" WHERE "guidelines"."title" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered guidelines/show.html.erb within layouts/application (18.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 83ms



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass):
    6:      
    7:          <div class="guideline span10">
    8:            
    9:          <p>Title: <%= link_to @guideline.title, seeguideline_path(@guideline.title) %> </p>
    10:             <strong> <a href="<%= @guideline.content %>", target = '_blank'>Link to guideline</a> </strong>
    11:             <p>Hospital Name: <%= @guideline.hospital %></p>
    12: 
  app/views/guidelines/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_guidelines_show_html_erb__4234346501713687788_70155056040280'
  app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb:132:in `show'
```

route is

```
get '/:title', to: 'guidelines#show', as: :seeguideline
```

Comment: Your `@guideline` isn't set. Your `where` clause isn't matching anything.

Comment: So first confirm in which form your result is appear with calling `.inspect()` on the object.

Comment: I'm unsure what to next meagar.  I previously has   @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id]) instead but changed this because of custom routes

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the title parameter in your action? What is the route, you're trying?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your route is passing the :title param?  What does your console log show for the SQL request for the query?  I have a feeling your route isn't passing what you think it's passing...

Also, you're going to want to handle the case that the query comes back empty anyway.  Having the app blow up probably isn't what you want.

Comment: No, app blowing up = bad outcome.  My route is get '/:title', to: 'guidelines#show', as: :seeguideline

Comment: have added the full console display

Comment: Your get is using id, not title. It's passing 35 to the show action.

Comment: Previously my routes had  get "profiles/show" and my show action was  @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id]).  The problem was that when I went to 'show' it showed /guidelines/35 whereas I wanted it to say /stackoverflo (i.e guideline title).  The changes I made did sort the routes but has obviously caused the other problem.